# How to integrate pressure over a sphere?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, integration, fluid-statics

> if I had a function for pressure $P(y)$ dependent on $y$ (vertical position) and I had a sphere in a stationary position, how would I integrate the pressure differential over the surface of the sphere to get a net force on the sphere?

Cartesian coordinates are also preferred :)

I found the pressure function for the situation myself, I just don't know how to get the net force.

Comment: When integrating over the surface of a sphere, it is almost always much easier to use spherical coordinates.

Comment: @G.Smith I understand this however this problem is a smaller part of a much larger problem that requires cartesian coordinates so I would like to keep it in cartesian coordinates :)

Comment: So the pressure is constant in the x and z directions?

Comment: @N.Steinle yes pressure only varies in the y-direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, take advantage of the nature of the problem:

1) by symmetry the result is only up/down, so $F_y$ is the only component you have to integrate

2) you can also just integrate along y  ( I.e just integral dy) by considering the force on rings of radius r(y)

3) now draw a force diagram for the upward component of the force on that ring: the trig simplifies quite nicely!

Comment: It's important to add that the pressure at all locations on the surface acts normal to the surface.